# Mybatis: how to map a class property stored in same table as parent class

Tags: mybatis

I have an Airport class, which is mapped to the following SQL table:

```
create TABLE AIRPORT (
  LATITUDE             NUMERIC(17, 6),
  LONGITUDE            NUMERIC(17, 6),
  COUNTRY_CDE          VARCHAR(2) not null,
  COM_CDE              VARCHAR(4) not null,
  TZ_CDE               VARCHAR(4),
  ... Additional columns ommitted
)
```

I would like to map this table to the `Airport` class as follows (in other words I would like to map the `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` columns to the `latLng` property, which is an instance of the `LatLng` class):

```
public class LatLng{
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;

   // getters and setters omitted
}

public class Airport{
   private LatLng latlng;
   ...
   LatLng getLatLng();
}
```

The obvious answer is to keep `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` as separate class members and then provide the actual mapping to `LatLng` directly in code. I was wondering if it possible to do the mapping directly with myBatis (as well as the other way around, ie map the `LatLng` property to the corresponding table columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK answering my own question. It turns out that it is super easy. In your mapper file, you simply need to indicate in your resultMap that the column is mapped to a complex property using the dot notation (Here latLng corresponds to the LatLng class instance):

```
<resultMap id="AirportResult" type="Airport">
        <id property="code" column="com_cde"/>
        <result property="latLng.latitude" column="latitude"/>
        <result property="latLng.longitude" column="longitude"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findByCode" parameterType="String" resultMap="AirportResult">
        SELECT com_cde,
        LATITUDE,
        LONGITUDE FROM AIRPORT
        WHERE com_cde = #{code}
    </select>
```